# pip module not found even after pip install Python 3.10

Tags: python, windows, powershell, pip, pycharm

I am using **PyCharm** editor for python coding and want to install `pyttsx3` library and also download from **cmd** not the problem is pycharm is not identifying the module as installed. Can you suggest what to do I am on Windows 10

[click to open error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2lwZ.png)

Comment: If you are using PyCharm, install the module in PyCharm (setting -> Project -> project environment). It is very probably you are installing the module in a different environment

Answer (score 0):

I see in your PyCharm instance that you have a specific interpreter called "jarvis". You need to make sure that the `pip install` command you are executing in the command prompt is installing this package in the site-packages folder of the jarvis interpreter.

You can install it in the same environment as Giacomo suggested using PyCharm to be sure. Click the "Terminal" tab and run the `pip install` command there.

Comment: I downloaded pip and it also shows successfully installed but showing error as no module found, 'jarvis' is the project name